# Agregar un objeto como parámetro a una Linkenlist

Tags: java, lista, jframe

Tengo un método para guardar una lista de vehículos con `linkendlist`, cada vehículo tiene una ruta, al momento de tratar de escoger del `combobox` las rutas no puedo guardarlas, ya que me sale un error que dice que son incompatibles.

JFRAME PARA EL INGRESO DE VEHICULOS

```
 private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            listaVehiculos.add(new Vehiculo(cmbRuta.getItemAt(cmbRuta.getSelectedIndex()), txtColor.getText(), txtPlaca.getText()));
            System.out.println("se agrego correctamente");
            tblVehiculos.setModel(listarVehiculos());
            guarde();
        }      

private javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel listarRutasEnComboBox() {
        javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<modelo.Ruta> modelo;
        modelo = new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < listaRuta.size(); i++) {
            modelo.addElement(listaRuta.get(i));
        }
        return modelo;
```

CLASE RUTA

```
package modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Ruta implements Serializable{
    private String identificador;
    private double distancia;

    public Ruta(String identificador, double distancia) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
        this.distancia = distancia;
    }

    public String getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }

    public void setIdentificador(String identificador) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }

    public double getDistancia() {
        return distancia;
    }

    public void setDistancia(double distancia) {
        this.distancia = distancia;
    }
}
```

CLASE VEHÍCULO.

```
package modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Vehiculo implements Serializable{
   private Ruta ruta; 
   private String placa, color;

    public Vehiculo(Ruta ruta, String placa, String color) {
        this.ruta = ruta;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Ruta getRuta() {
        return ruta;
    }

    public void setRuta(Ruta ruta) {
        this.ruta = ruta;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias agregar el error que te esta saliendo?

Comment: Bienvenido a https://es.stackoverflow.com, echa un vistazo https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para tener una mejor idea de cómo postear una pregunta. Es necesario que coloques el error tal y como se muestra.

Answer (score 0):

[![este es el error que me muestra, trato de guardar un vehículo agregándole una ruta pero me sale que son incompatibles ya que el parámetro ruta es de tipo Ruta y no se como agregarlo][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYYQB.png [1]

Comment: deberías agregar este error en la pregunta y no dejarlo como una respuesta, puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar el error que te muestra